# Install SSL on a Nginx server in a azure VM

Tags: ssl, azure-virtual-machine

I have issued an SSL certificate and now I tried to access using `ssh` to the config file to install my certificate issued, but it's showing an error, can you please tell me how can I install my SSL certificate on portal.azure.com, I have NGINX server

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't install an SSL certificate in Azure VM via the portal but you can use **cloud-init** to install packages and write files, or to configure users and security.

When you create a VM, certificates and keys are stored in the protected `/var/lib/waagent/` directory. To automate adding the certificate to the VM and configuring the web server, use cloud-init. In this example, you install and configure the NGINX web server. You can use the same process to install and configure Apache.

Create a file named `cloud-init-web-server.txt` and paste the following configuration:

```
#cloud-config
package_upgrade: true
packages:
  - nginx
write_files:
  - owner: www-data:www-data
  - path: /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
    content: |
      server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/mycert.cert;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/mycert.prv;
      }
runcmd:
  - secretsname=$(find /var/lib/waagent/ -name "*.prv" | cut -c -57)
  - mkdir /etc/nginx/ssl
  - cp $secretsname.crt /etc/nginx/ssl/mycert.cert
  - cp $secretsname.prv /etc/nginx/ssl/mycert.prv
  - service nginx restart
```

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/tutorial-secure-web-server